# how to save datagridview bulk data to sql database while the datagridview data binded with images to SQL database in c#

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview

There are many questions similar to my issue,but none of them helped away from this issue..
I'm working with win-forms, coding in C#, using SQL server

I have a datagridview which is retrieving data from database with some data as text and some are images.
My code is as given below to save the datagridview data to database
but this is not working and throwing an error **an object or column name is missing or empty. for select into statements verify ..........**
Please solve my issue..

```
try
        {
            ConnectionStringSettings consettings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["attendancemanagement"];
            string connectionString = consettings.ConnectionString;
            string StrQuery;
            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand())
                    {
                        comm.Connection = conn;
                        conn.Open();
                        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
                        {
                            StrQuery = @"INSERT INTO dailydemo VALUES ("
                + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["S_No"].Value + ", "
                + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Employee_Id"].Value + ", "
                + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Employee_Name"].Value + ", "
                + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["In_time"].Value + ", "
                + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Out_Time"].Value + ", "
                + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Date"].Value + ", "
                + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Week_No_of_The_Month"].Value + ", "
                + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Attendance"].Value + ", "
                + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Work_status"].Value + ", "
                + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Remarks"].Value + ", "
                + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Image_of_Employee"].Value + ");";
                            comm.CommandText = StrQuery;
                            comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this may be Help full...

```
byte[] imgByteArrLogo = new byte[0];
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Your Connection string Here"))
            {
                if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                {
                    con.Open();
                }
                using (SqlTransaction _pTrans = con.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted))
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Image_of_Employee"].Value != null)
                        {
                            Image _dgvImage = (Image)dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Image_of_Employee"].Value;
                            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                            _dgvImage.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                            imgByteArrLogo = new byte[ms.Length];
                            ms.Position = 0;
                            ms.Read(imgByteArrLogo, 0, imgByteArrLogo.Length);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            imgByteArrLogo = new byte[0];
                        }

                        try
                        {
                            string sql = "INSERT INTO dailydemo (S_No,Employee_Id ,Employee_Name ,In_time ,Out_Time ,Date,Week_No_of_The_Month,Attendance,Work_status,Remarks,Image_of_Employee) VALUES (@S_No,@Employee_Id ,@Employee_Name ,@In_time ,@Out_Time ,@Date,@Week_No_of_The_Month,@Attendance,@Work_status,@Remarks,@Image_of_Employee)";
                            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con, _pTrans))
                            {
                                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@S_No", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["S_No"].Value));
                                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Employee_Id", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Employee_Id"].Value));
                                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Employee_Name", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Employee_Name"].Value));
                                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@In_time", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["In_time"].Value));
                                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Out_Time", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Out_Time"].Value));
                                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Week_No_of_The_Month", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Week_No_of_The_Month"].Value));
                                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Attendance", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Attendance"].Value));
                                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Work_status", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Work_status"].Value));
                                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Remarks", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Remarks"].Value));
                                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Image_of_Employee", imgByteArrLogo));
                                cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception exp)
                        {
                            _pTrans.Rollback();
                            con.Close();
                            _pTrans.Dispose();
                            MessageBox.Show(exp.Message, "Error!!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                        }
                    }
                    _pTrans.Commit();
                    _pTrans.Dispose();
                    con.Close();
                }
            }
```

**UPDATE :**

Please note that in this example I used your datagridview cell name as sql table column names, if column names are diffrent then modify it.

Comment: I'm facing with this  error
unable to cast object of type 'system.byte ' to type 'system.drawing.image' in c#